# How to plot circle around data point in Julia's Gadfly?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

Would like to plot circle with specified radius, color, around data point in Julia's Gadfly? Is this achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set `default_color` and `panel_fill` the same:

```
julia> tm=Theme(panel_fill=colorant"black", default_color=colorant"black");

julia> plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10),tm)
```

[image]

EDIT:
to control points size and width:

```
julia> tm.default_point_size=4pt
julia> tm.highlight_width=4pt
```

while circle colors is determined by `highlight_color()` function related to their fill color.

Comment: Is it possible to control the size and fill color of those white circles on your plot?

Comment: Also I think that it's possible to set default_color=colorant"transparent" then implement custom `highlight_color()` function.